# Web applications: Parallel changes of data in repository

Tags: java, spring

I'm currently architecting a web application (moderately modern) that can do some easy data mangling from and to a database. I'm thinking of potential problems already.

Suppose a user logs into the web app and loads some data from the repository. (S)He changes the data, then wants to write it back to the database.

How to prevent the following scenarios in a standardized way:

- (S)He logged in twice and has already saved some data in the second session that will be lost when saving from the first session.
- Some other user loaded the data and is now changing it, who will potentially overwrite our changes.

I don't want to say 2 phase commit, and I'm not going to roll my own version of it. Preventing the same user to log in twice (user singleton), coupled with a strict permissions management can solve the first problem. But if business requirements allow multiple agents to see and alter the same data, I'm still at a loss.

Are there differentiation libraries/algorithms that test the data that wants to be written before it is, if the assumptions while reading hold up? How is this solved usually, for larger commercial applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would choose between two main strategies:

- Optimistic locking
- Pessimistic locking

**Optimistic locking:** You save a version (number) together with id of your objects in the repository (database). Before saving new objects you check the version of the old object you about to overwrite. If the version doesn't match the version of the edited object, you abort saving and report to the user, that the object in the repository was changed. If version match, you overwrite old object with the new one and increase the version.

**Pessimistic locking**: You lock object before user start altering it. If object already locked, you show the message, that the current object being edited by another user.
This can be done either in a single transaction using DB-locking and say Statefull beans or using separate use defined field.

Pessimistic locking is more complicated to implement, but it provides better user experience, since it prevents user to enter the data and then reenter it again, if optimistic lock exception occurred.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjhz.html for more information.

Comment: I can see that by "You" in "Optimistic locking", you refer to a bean, which makes the thing that much easier. That seems like a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0):

In most (by most I mean almost all) applications, this is done using an [ACID database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) like Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL.

Comment: In a web application context, doesn't that still require a distributed transaction protocol?

Comment: @0xCAFEBABE: Of course not. The reason people pay lots of money to say Oracle is because it does that for you. The JPA API that is mentioned in the accepted answer also delegates to the database under the hood. Have a read at this article here. It talks about how modern DBs do concurrency control: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control